# Adicionar o admob em um layout navigation drawer

Tags: android

Quero colocar a propaganda no rodapé da activity, mas fica no topo sobrepondo uma lista:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#4DA6FF"
    android:background="#FFF"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listaPropaganda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Java, no oncreate da activity:

```
AdView ads = new AdView(this);
    ads.setAdUnitId(ANUNCIO_ID);
    ads.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listaPropaganda);
    layout.addView(ads);

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("1100").build();
    ads.loadAd(request);
```

Quero colocar no rodapé e preenchendo todo o espaço. Como fazer isso?

---

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#4DA6FF"
    android:background="#FFF"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listaPropaganda"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitua o seu layout por esse abaixo. Observe que eu troquei o `FrameLayout` externo por um `LinearLayout` com `android:orientation="vertical"`. Observe também que foi adicionada a propriedade `android:layout_weight="1"` na sua lista. A altura dela passou para `0dp` por questões de otimização, já que o weight definirá que ela deverá preencher todo o espaço que sobrar entre as duas views.

Se preferir, inclusive, você pode tirar o `listaPropaganda` do layout e adicionar seu banner diretamente no `container`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#4DA6FF"
        android:background="#FFF"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listaPropaganda"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Não deu certo, ele fez o menu drawer sumir, segue o código original, no primeiro sumiu drawer:

Comment: Tente colocar o `layout_gravity="start"` no `LinearLayout` de id "container", o `MenuDrawer` precisa ter um `gravity`.

Comment: A dica do Wakim foi de fundamental importancia, e foi preciso colocar minha lista fora do linearlayout, obrigado pela ajuda